# Android 3.0 build gradle errors

Tags: android, android-studio

please see this errors in this picture 
[image]

this is the app.build iv'e just installed android studio 3.0
and this is the errors in the picture
dont know what to do anymore please help me

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.

Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Required by:
    project :app

> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.24.14] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Connection timed out: connect

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mahilum.meebot"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Please Add Error Msg

Comment: no the code that is needed to change is already there please see the picture

Answer (score 2):

Please add below line in app build gradle file.

```
 android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        flavorDimensions "default"
    }
```

Comment: it wont work for me

Comment: plz clean you project add flavorDimensions "default" this line as i suggest you. try once with clean your project.

Comment: its not really working, its just stuck up again